# relative paths for modules in python

Tags: python, relative-path, python-module, python-packaging

I've attempted a few different techniques trying to do something that to me seems doable but I guess I am missing some gotchas about python (using 2.7 but would like this to work also for 3.* if possible).

I am not sure about terminology like package or module, but to me the following seems quite a "simple" doable scenario.

This is the directory structure:

```
.
├── job
│   └── the_script.py
└── modules
    ├── __init__.py
    └── print_module.py
```

The content of `the_script.py`:

```
# this does not work
import importlib
print_module = importlib.import_module('.print_module', '..modules')

# this also does not work
from ..modules import print_module

print_module.do_stuff()
```

The content of `print_module`:

```
def do_stuff():
    print("This should be in stdout")
```

I would like to run all this "relative paths" stuff as:

```
/job$ python2 the_script.py
```

But the `importlib.import_module` gives various errors:

- if I just use 1 input parameter `..modules.print_module`, then I get: `TypeError("relative imports require the 'package' argument")`
- if I use 2 input parameters (as in the example above), then I get: `ValueError: Empty module name`

On the other hand using the `from ..modules` syntax I get: `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`.

I think the `__init__.py` empty file should be enough to qualify that code as "packages" (or modules? not sure about the terminology), but it seems there's something I am missing about how to manage relative paths.

I read that in the past people was hacking this using the `path` and other functions from `import os` and `import sys`, but according to the official docs (python 2.7 and 3.*) this should not be needed anymore.

What am I doing wrong and how could I achieve the result of printing the content `modules/print_module.do_stuff` calling it from a script in the "relative directory" `job/`?

Comment: Why would you use importlib here? Why not just import it directly?

Comment: `__init__.py` only creates a package for the directory it is in.  You need to add `__init__.py` to *all* directories in the tree you showed.  You will also need to make sure the directory containing the top-level package directory is on `sys.path`, and if you want to be able to execute one of the files as a script, you'll need to think about the issues described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/how-to-fix-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution using `sys` and `os`.

The script `the_script.py` should be:

```
import sys
import os
lib_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../modules'))
sys.path.append(lib_path)

# commenting out the following shows the `modules` directory in the path
# print(sys.path)

import print_module

print_module.do_stuff()
```

Then I can run it via command line no matter where I am in the path e.g.:

- `/job$ python2 the_script.py`
- `<...>/job$ python2 <...>/job/the_script.py`

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. Also puzzling: almost as if they have deliberately made things so you can't use a relative path for imports (or have to jump through hoops to do so).

Answer (score 4):

If you follow the structure of this guide here: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/#test-suite (highly recommend reading it all, it is very helpful) you will see this:

> To give the individual tests import context, create a tests/context.py file:
>
> ```
> import os
> import sys
> sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))
>
> import sample
> ```
>
> Then, within the individual test modules, import the module like so:
>
> ```
> from .context import sample
> ```
>
> This will always work as expected, regardless of installation method.

Translated in your case this means:

```
root_folder
├── job
│   ├── context.py <- create this file
│   └── the_script.py
└── modules
    ├── __init__.py
    └── print_module.py
```

In the `context.py` file write the lines shown above, but `import modules` instead of `import samples`

Finally in your `the_script.py`: `from .context import module` and you will be set to go!

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks :) but this gives: `ImportError: No module named modules.print_module`

Comment: In python 2 this gives `ImportError: No module named airflow_stuff.modules.print_module`, in python 3 it gives a similar error message

Comment: That way of using a context via `sys.path` gives `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`, sorry to keep pointing out these details but it does not seem to work, however I found a similar solution I posted in an answer here though it seems quite close to yours so not sure why in your case it raises an error.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not sure about terminology go to very nice tutorials:

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/#modules

and

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/#packages

But for your structure:

```
.
├── job
│   └── the_script.py
└── modules
    ├── __init__.py
    └── print_module.py
```

just say in the `the_script.py`:

```
import sys
sys.append('..')
import modules.print_module
```

This will add parent directory to PYTHONPATH, and python will see directory 'parallel' to job directory and it will work.

I think that at the most basic level it is sufficent to know that:

1. **package** is any directory with `__init__.py` file
2. **module** is a file with `.py`, but when you are importing module you omit extension.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the docs :) but this gives: `ImportError: No module named modules.print_module`

Comment: In python 2 this gives `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'append'`, however if I put instead `sys.path.append('..')`, then this gives `ImportError: No module named modules.print_module`. In python 3 it gives similar error messages.